# Swagger doesn't read Path parameter: @Path("folder{path:.*}")

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger, resteasy, swagger-ui

I have a problem getting Swagger to generate correct documentation for an API call that has an optional path parameter.

I'm building an API that peers into a hierarchical structure, similar to a file system. I want to call the same method to get the root structure as I do to get a sub resource. E.g:
Get the root: /folder
Get a sub folder: /folder/path/to

My Jax-rs method looks like this:

```
@GET @Path("folder{path:.*}")
Response folderContents(@ApiParam(value = "The folder to list", required = false) @PathParam("path") String path)
{...}
```

My method call works, but my swagger documentation is incorrect and doesn't work. Swagger-ui generates GET calls that look like this when I run it:

http://localhost:8080/storage-war/rest/filestore/folder{path:.*}

I'm looking for a way to either force Swagger to generate the correct signature or rebuild my regular expression so that my generated Swagger is correct.

Previously I'v tried using *@Path("folder/{path:.*}")*; his generated correct Swagger documentation but didn't match my no path given case. I've also tried *@Path("/folder{p:/?}{path:(.*)}")*; This produced a working method call but incorrect Swagger docs.

Is there a straightforward way to do what I'm looking for?

**Edit:**

In the end I created separate method calls for root and folders. Then I decorated the root call with  it with @ApiOperation(hidden = true). This way I have an extra method in my code but only one method show up in my Swagger docs.

```
@GET @Path("folder/{path:.*}")
Response folderContents(@PathParam("path") String path)
{...}

@GET @Path("folder")
@ApiOperation(hidden = true)
Response rootContents()
{...}
```

Answer (score 1):

In swagger, path parameters are *always* required.  Understanding that in many frameworks and in practice they can be optional, but in the swagger definition they are required.  See https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#fixed-fields-7